# Select and order by most matches

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Let's say I explode a string passed in a search. Example: <strike>"if there was a dog"</strike> **"if there were a dog"** (silly American).

We explode based on " " so results...

```
if
there
were
a
dog
```

Now I want to run a `SQL select * from table_name query where column_name like 
'%something%' or column_name like '%somethingelse%'...`

I'm trying to determine how I can search a table and order by rows that contain the most matches. (ie, if row **45** contained *4* of the above split items and row **21** only contained *2*, row **45** should be displayed at top in the results).

This would be a primitive "search relevance" logic. Is there a specific term for this kind of retrieval in SQL?

Suggestions?

Comment: "if there *were* a dog" ;)

Comment: I just had to reboot after seeing that. Was never aware I had that memory leak from elementary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just put the comparisons in the `order by` clause, use `case` statements to convert them to 0/1, and add them up:

```
select *
from table_name query
where column_name like '%something%' or column_name like '%somethingelse%'
order by ((case when column_name like '%something%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when column_name like '%somethingelse%' then 1 else 0 end)
          . . .
         ) desc
```

I would be inclined to write the query as:

```
select (Match1+Match2+. . .) as NumMatches, <rest of columns>
from (select t.*,
             (case when column_name like '%something%' then 1 else 0 end) as Match1,
             . . .
      from tablename
     ) t
order by NumMatches desc
```

Comment: how do you tweak this for counting the matches against an array:

t.title ~~* any(array['%string1%', '%string2%'])

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet . . . A new question should be asked as a *question* not a *comment*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a variation of @Gordon's excellent answer:

```
SELECT FieldToSearch, 
  CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% if %' then 1 else 0 end
      + CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% there %' then 1 else 0 end 
      + CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% was %' then 1 else 0 end
      + CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% a %' then 1 else 0 end
      + CASE WHEN ' ' + FieldToSearch + ' ' like '% dog %' then 1 else 0 end matches
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY matches DESC
```

And here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/13b33/10).

Best of luck!