# how to search string against array of keywords and order results based on number of matches in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I saw a similar answer here:

[Select and order by most matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759532/select-and-order-by-most-matches/14759590)

and was wondering how to adapt it. Actually pretty shocked that the order statement below works. But was wondering how to adapt it for use against an array of keywords.

array['happy','birthday'.. x more keywords]

```
select *
from table_name query
where column_name like '%something%' or column_name like '%somethingelse%'
order by ((case when column_name like '%something%' then 1 else 0 end) +
          (case when column_name like '%somethingelse%' then 1 else 0 end)
          . . .
         ) desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `unnest()` and `count(*)` in a subquery:

```
select v.*,
       (select count(*)
        from  unnest(array['this', '2', 'is']) pat
        where str like '%' || pat || '%'
       ) cnt
from (values ('this is a test'), ('test 2 x')) v(str) 
order by cnt desc
```